# Is there a way to make hx-trigger dependent on the selected value?

Tags: htmx

I have a  box with multiple options. For certain options, I need to display another select, but not for the other ones.

```
<select>
  <option value="scala">Scala</option>
  <option value="java">Java</option>
</select>
```

Is there some way in hx-trigger to only perform the trigger based on the value of the selected option?

Comment: Does this help you? https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/